# Uploading Media gives error "Missing a temporary folder."

Tags: media, filesystem

After we upgraded to Wordpress 3.0.1 (from Wordpress MU 2.9.2) we began getting an error message whenever we tried to upload media.

**"Missing a temporary folder"**

Various articles around the web mention the php setting `upload_tmp_dir` needing to be set in `php.ini`. This is not actually a requirement. I know because it is not set in our test environment, and it was not set in our production environment before the deploy. In both cases uploads worked.

So what changed?

I have *an* answer, but I'm not sure it's the definitive answer. I'll post mine.

Answer (score 2):

`upload_tmp_dir` is an optional setting in `php.ini`. Php will attempt to use the system default temp directory. So it should *just work*.

If something happens to the permissions on your temp directory, regardless of wether you set it in `php.ini` or use the system default (usually `/tmp` on unix like systems), then media uploads will fail.  You will see the same error **"Missing a temporary folder"** if folder doesn't exist, but also if you don't have proper permissions on the temporary directory.

Your web server, Apache or whatever, is probably running as nobody, or some other account with basically no rights to anything. So the first thing to check is that `/tmp` is globally writable.

On unix like systems it goes something like this. I'm assuming that your system default temp directory is `/tmp`. From the command line

```
$ ls -l /tmp
lrwxrwxrwx@ 1 root  admin  11 Sep 10 11:40 /tmp
```

The first bit `lrwxrwxrwx` should look just like that. No dashes. If not

```
$ chmod 777 /tmp
```

and if it gives you permissions errors

```
$ sudo chmod 777 /tmp
```

You'll need the root password.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering to this old question, as a lot of people are facing the same issue in 2018. You can fix the missing temporary folder error using cPanel. Follow these steps:
Head to cpanel.

1. Click on **File Manager**.
2. Click on **public_html** in the left-hand sidebar.
3. Find **wp-config.php** file. Right-click on it
   and choose **Edit**.
4. A pop up will appear. Click on the **Edit** button.
5. A new tab will be opened. Add the following line:

   ```
   define('WP_TEMP_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-content/temp/');
   ```
6. Now, go to the previous tab of file manager. Open the **wp-content**
   directory.
7. Create a new folder by clicking on **+Folder** in the cPanel
   navigation menu.
8. A pop up will appear. Add **temp** in the box below **New Folder
   Name**.
9. Click on the **Create New Folder** button.
10. Refresh the page to see the new folder.

Now, you will find that the missing temporary folder issue is gone. You can find more information about these steps [right here](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-fix-the-missing-a-temporary-folder-error-of-a-wordpress-site-using-cpanel/).